# Why solution to differential equation not the same as compound interest?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The Amount $y(t)$ on a bank account with interest of 5% can be described by this DE:

$$\frac{dy}{dt} = 0.05y$$

when solving this I get:

$$y = y_0 · e^{0.05t}$$

where $e^{0.05} ≈ 1,0512711 ...$

But I know the right answer is

$$y = y_0 · (1.05000)^t$$

Why is the first answer not exactly the same as the second?

Comment: Your differential equation gives the case when the interest is compounded once every infinitesimal moment, while the "right" answer is the interest compounded yearly

Comment: Is the DE appropriate to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solution for the differential equation is a function on a continuous time interval. But the second one is the discrete equation for the compound interest. Always the value of the continuous function is little higher than the discrete function. This is because, when we are calculating compound interest by second equation, we apply the rate yearly, monthly, etc neglecting the continuous increment.

Comment: In fact, $$\lim_{n\to\infty} y_0 \left(1 + \frac{a}{n} \right)^{nt} = y_0 e^{at},$$ so in the limit of continuously compounded interest, you get the solution to the differential equation.